# JGitFlow maven plugin doesn't push release branch to remote

Tags: git, maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I'm using `jGitFlow` plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <pushFeatures>true</pushFeatures>
        <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
        <pushHotfixes>true</pushHotfixes>
        <noDeploy>true</noDeploy>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn jgitflow:feature-start` and enter branch name (say `testSomething`) it got pushed to origin immediately. I can see that by listing branches `git branch -a`:

```
* feature/testSomething
  remotes/origin/feature/testSomething
```

So far so good. But now I'm doing `mvn jgitflow:release-start`. I enter the new version, next development version and the goal runs to completion. I'm on the newly created release branch but this branch is not pushed to remote. What I'm doing wrong? Is this intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that our git repository can be only amended via pull-requests and hence the push didn't work. It's a bit shame the plugin ignores the return value of the push and doesn't at least emit a warning.

Comment: Did you try running it with `-X`? Maybe it is inside some debug information.

Comment: I did, yes. I even cloned the jgiflow plugin from bitbucket and debugged it through to see what's going on :) So I can claim that the result of the push is silently ignored

Comment: Another similar situation is when you allow pushes to develop branch for functional user and you use a branch name filter to allow only names like ^([fF]eature|[bB]ugfix|hot[fF]ix)|/(.+?)$ where release/ is missing from allowed names. The push will fail silently and jgitflow will not warn you.